# How to pass a view value to a controller on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller called items_controller, I need to send a value to it using my **unanswered.html.erb** view.

But I'm not getting it, my view makes an each and I need each value of that each to call the controller and receive the value of that controller

**items_controller.erb**

```
class MercadoLivre::ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_items

  def items
    @details = @get_item_service.item_details
    @item = @details.body
  end

  private

  def set_items
    @get_item_service = MercadoLivre::Items.new
  end
end
```

My service **items.rb**

```
module MercadoLivre
  class Items
    include HTTParty

    base_uri 'https://api.mercadolibre.com'

    def initialize(mlb_code_id)
      @mlb_code = mlb_code_id
      @options = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ****'
        }
      }
    end

    def item_details
      self.class.get("/items/#{@mlb_code}", @options)
    end
  end
end
```

my view **unanswered.html.erb**

```
<div>
  <p class="text-2xl mb-3">Perguntas não respondidas</p>
  <%= button_to "Ver perguntas respondidas", questions_answered_path, method: :get, class: "mb-5 mt-5 text-red-700" %>

<div>
  <% @list['questions'].each do |q| %>
  <div class="flex flex-col">
    <div>
      <p class="font-bold">Pergunta: </p>
      <p><%= q['text'] %> </p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <p class="font-bold">Item:</p>
      <p><%= q['item_id'] %> </p>

      <%# pass value to controller items_controllers.rb here %>
    </div>

    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">

    </textarea>

    <button class="mt-5">Responder</button>
  </div>

  <% end %>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a new instance of MercadoLivre::Items with the correct number of parameters it was defined;

```
def set_items
  @get_item_service = MercadoLivre::Items.new(1) # you need a value for +mlb_code+
end
```